# Remove # from References using knitcitations package

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, bibtex, bibliography

I need to remove `#` symbol from my Rmarkdown document, 
specific at References section. I use an external `.bib` archive called **biblio.bib**.

My YAML header is:

```
---
output: 
    pdf_document:
      number_sections: true
header-includes:
  - \usepackage[spanish]{babel}     
  - \usepackage{cite}
bibliography: biblio.bib
---
```

and at References section I use `knitcitations` package:

````
# Referencias {-}




```{r generateBibliography, echo=FALSE, eval=TRUE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
require("knitcitations")
cleanbib()
read.bibtex(file = "biblio.bib")
```
````

My `pdf_document` output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you don't rely on *knitcitations* I can provide an alternative solution:

Open your *biblio.bib* in an editor and you should find something like `@article{einstein_relativity_1925, ...`. (Perhaps it's more feasible to use a program like [JabRef](http://www.jabref.org/).) Now in your text you can simply cite like this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo 
ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis
parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus [@einstein_relativity_1925].
```

which yields:

> ..., nascetur ridiculus mus (Einstein, 1925).

or set a leading minus if only the year is needed:

```
However, Einstein [-@einstein_relativity_1925] concluded ...
```

which yields:

> Einstein (1925) concluded ...

Now watch that your *biblio.bib* is in the same directory as your **.Rmd*-File and add the following at the end of your paper:

````
# Referencias
```{r refmgr references, results="asis", echo=FALSE}
```
````

When knitting to PDF all the references you used should now be listed automatically and alphabetically:

> **Referencias**
>
> Einstein, A. (1925). Relativity theory. Physics, 2nd edition. Teubner, Leipzig.
>
> Einstein, A. (1927). ...
>
> ...

PS: You can now delete the   `- \usepackage{cite}` line out of your YAML header.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, it is best to use pandoc native citation as proposed in @jaySf's answer.

However, your problem can be solved with chunk option `results="asis"`. Currently, your chunk's output is formatted as code, although it should be formatted as text. Results controls that. See the [chunk options documentation](http://yihui.name/knitr/options).

````
```{r generateBibliography, results="asis", echo=FALSE, eval=TRUE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
require("knitcitations")
cleanbib()
read.bibtex(file = "biblio.bib")
```
````